# How to save several asc files to geotiff

Tags: qgis, convert, geotiff-tiff, export

In QGIS (2.18), I have several raster files (.asc-format) that have no projection information. 
The images display well at EPSG:5677. My aim is to store all the files in a new folder, using the GeoTIFF format and assigning EPSG:5677.

I have no python experience, however some python coding could help me here, I guess. I read something similar but shapefile-related here:
[Exporting several files at same time in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131104/exporting-several-files-at-same-time-in-qgis)

Of course, this doesn't work with my raster files. So here goes my question: how can I export a bunch of raster files, using the original file names and assigning the desired coordinate reference system without having to export every single file manually?

Comment: Do you have ArcGIS? Also, if you have experience in R, I would suggest a very simple workaround.

Comment: No, I don't have ArcGIS. I wouldn't call myself experienced in R, but I do use it from time to time. However, I've never worked with geodata in R.

Comment: I have provided a solution in R, since you mentioned that you use it from time to time. Let me know if that helps. It's much quicker than doing it manually in QGIS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208617/convert-batch-file-using-gdal-translate (which was closed as off-topic, but has answers).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49919166/batch-process-multiple-ascii-to-raster-files-in-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the User's comment that they would be open to trying this in R, here's the solution:

```
#Load the three packages below 
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

#List the files that you want to export from the source folder
files <- list.files(path="C:\\Users\\.", pattern="asc$", full.names=TRUE) #selects all the asc files in the directory
s <- stack(files) # stack all of them using r raster library
proj4string(s) <- CRS("+init=epsg:5677") #Sets it to the projection you wanted
newname<-paste("C:\\Users\\",names(s)) #Saves the previous names
writeRaster(s,newname, bylayer=T, format="GTiff")#Edited based on Fumy's comment
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me.
However, I preferred to keep the original file names, so I specified the location by
> newname<-paste("C:\\Users\\",names(s))
and then stored the files
> writeRaster(s,newname, bylayer=T, format="GTiff")

Comment: Thanks @F.Fumy. That's a great suggestion. Updated it to reflect your edits.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have QGIS, you therefore also have GDAL installed on your machine.  So I suggest you adapt the example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691943/how-to-loop-through-several-files-using-gdal-and-cmd) over on Stackexchange and create a batch file.

In your case, you will also want to set the gdal_translate a_srs switch to 5677 and change the -of switch (see [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)).  So the relevant line in the batch file will be something like this:

```
gdal_translate -of "GTiff" -a_srs 5677 %mypath%!infile! %mypath%!outfile!
```

If you leave out the -of switch altogether, it will default to GeoTiff anyway. I just wanted to differentiate from the example given in the link.  If you do not have an environment variable set for gdal_translate (which in a standard osgeo4w installation probably won't be the case) then you will have to run this command from the osgeo4w bin folder (in my case `c:\osgeo4w64\bin`).

Comment: I guess it should be `GTiff` instead of `GTif`, should not it? (on edit version May 23'17, accessed June 15'18)

Comment: Indeed.  On this point it is worth noting a small change since I gave this answer originally and that is that GTiff is no longer the default here and GDAL will guess 
 the format based on the extension.