# Raster Conversion set output path [GDAL]

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate

I planned to use gdal_translate to convert raster from uncompressed RGB geotiff to compressed(JPEG compression) YCBCR geotiff as a batch process. So I have created a .bat file using this code

```
for %%i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES %%i %%.tif
```

The code works fine but the problem is output rasters are created in the same path of input rasters. For example If input raster name is **RGB.tif**, after processing .bat file output created in the same folder with the name of **RGB.tif.tif**.

Is there any possibility to store output tiff in a separate directory? I have kept my input rasters in directory *D:\work\RGB* and I want to store output rasters in *D:\work\YCBCR* with the same name of Input.

Comment: `for %%i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES %%i C:\Your\NewPath\%%~nxi.tif`

Comment: Luke's comment will probably get you what you need, but if not, you'd be better off searching on [SO]. This isn't really a GIS question, but a question about batch file variables and constructing paths.

Comment: @Luke I will check and let you know

Comment: @EvilGenius Ok I will post such questions on Stack Overflow next time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert batch file using GDAL_Translate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/208617/2856)

Comment: @Luke Thanks for your valuable information! I have used `for %%i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES %%i D:\work\YCBCR\%%~nxi` to get output images in the same name at defined path. Post it as answer, so that it may help others

Comment: If you are interested in an explanation why Luke's code works take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262218/batch-processing-multiple-files-with-mcc-lidar/263106#263106.